# How do I display a Simple Google Map in my emulator in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I tried to write a simple google map application to display simple map but doesn't give me any output.

I pasted my code below:

### AnroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.HelloGoogleMaps"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


        <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My layout file is:

### map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0Z1oyeAgSpj4FSEtenPqiL7RsCXA_pVPQhvtpdA"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my java class file is:

### HelloGoogleMaps.java

```
package org.HelloGoogleMaps;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class HelloGoogleMaps extends Activity {
      @Override

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    }

    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
     return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed up the formatting for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see your layout file, but have you set a proper API key?

http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

Comment: We r running our internet from proxy server so for that i have to change the debug configuration of my project and change the target as:-http-proxy http://192.168.0.1:8080/

Comment: @azad: "thank a lot for yr response brother" is best expressed "[by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)" [that is the most helpful to you]

Answer (score 0):

Your HelloGoogleMaps should inherit the MapsActivity 
Just change your code to

```
public class HelloGoogleMaps extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```